# pandas check if individual values in DataFrame are digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe that looks as such:

```
   a      b        c       d
-1000   2000.1     NaN    text1
NaN     -500       450    text2
1240.6   NaN       -100   text3
```

Some values contain a decimal, some contain a negative sign, and some are integer.

I want to unify the format of all the columns containing integers to be floats with 0s. i.e `-1000` should be `-1000.000` and so on.

The approach i'm taking is fairly simple, but it doesn't do the trick. I have tried this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str) + '.000' if x.str.isnumeric().all() else x)
```

However this function doesn't work as intended as it checks if the entire pd.Series is numeric, which is not always the case.

How can I improve this function to look through each individual value and add the `.000` as necessary?

Comment: If you just want to change the [style of dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Comment: > entire pd.Series is numeric, which is not always the case.  How come it's not? numpy arrays can't have mixed types. Or you meant that some series are not numeric? Then you can use df.dtypes to only check on numeric columns. Also please note, that once you see a column of specific type, all its cells are casted to this type, so e.g. 500 in a float64 column is a float internally, but shown to you as originally read in.
May be you can rephrase your question based on this

Answer (score 0):

IIUC similar your current method, you can try a custom function with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) , note that formatting a float would change the dtypes

```
def myf(x):
    s = pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')
    return np.where(pd.notna(s),'{0:.3f}'.format(s),x)

df.applymap(myf)
```

---

```
           a         b         c      d
0  -1000.000  2000.100       nan  text1
1        nan  -500.000   450.000  text2
2   1240.600       nan  -100.000  text3
```

Comment: This is working however it fills all the values in column 'd' as nan?

Comment: @ramez not for me as you can see the output column d stays the same, can you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function:

```
def floatStr3(x):
    try:
        return f'{float(x):.3f}'
    except:
        return x
```

Then apply it to each element:

```
df.applymap(floatStr3)
```